Over Voltage Protection Circuit
I’ve been trying to figure out how this circuit works but I don't quite understand the point of D32.
D23 is a 33V Zener
D32 is a 15V Zener
D19 is a Schottky it just has the wrong symbol.
Q24 is a P-channel MOSFET array.
This is supposed to protect the 24 V line from voltage spikes above 31 V.


Drawing the circuit with proper MOSFET symbols, arranged to make the circuit easier to parse, it seems that D32 is clamping M1's \$V_{GS}\$ to some limit, to prevent it from exceeding the transistor's absolute maximum rating. That limit is not clear, though:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A simulation shows \$V_{GS}\$ (orange) never exceeding 18V or so:

The output (blue) cuts of when the input exceeds 36V, not 31V, which makes more sense. The orange trace shows M1's \$V_{GS}\$ getting very loosely clamped, but it's not ideal. What doesn't make sense (to me) is why D32 is placed where it is. I would think it does a better job directly between M1's gate and source:

simulate this circuit

Are you sure that your circuit has D32 placed correctly?

I inherited this design and been trying to understand it. I agree that D32's placement is strange. I think what you suggested makes sense

D32 is likely to be used for clamping. If you're saying that it's a 15V Zener, then it's going to clamp 15V off of the input voltage to Vgs, which will serve to act as a protection for excessive Vgs. For example, suppose VIN24 reaches 31V (as you mentioned) instead of 24V. The voltage you will see at the gate shall not exceed 18V. According to your datasheet for your dual-PMOS device, it specifically says that Vgs (at room temperature at 25'C) has an absolute rating of +/- 20V.

A gate-drain clamp? That's an unusual use case.

That makes sense but Im confused why D2 is connected to G1. Wouldnt you need a seperate resistor to ground? Or is it the same thing?

@Xarak I'm assuming you mean D23. But when D23 conducts, it'll pull the gate low to ground if there's an overvoltage event. R77 is already pulling the gates up already under normal conditions. If you added a pull-down resistor, you would be messing that up with a voltage divider and messing up FET behavior under normal operation.

D32 starts to conduct at 15V, and brings down the voltage of Vgs to ~20V, without it Vgs would be exceeded. Without it Vgs follows a linear curve (with no 'knee' bending at 15V)

